# How to resolve this GAE status 500 error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi
I'm looking for how to resolve an error on the production server where
AFAIK the instruction looks correct:

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
```

When at the log it says

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: cannot import name template
```

On the local dev server it works normally. I suspect it's a problem with starting an instance on the production server. The appengine console says there totally is 1 instance.
Could you please inform how I could proceed?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem this morning.

If you just updated to the new version (1.4) that was released today, you might need to update you paths. (I use mac and hade do lunch the Google App Engine Launcher to set the new paths.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For me the local dev server works normally and this error I see is on the production server. Did you experience it on local dev server only or also on production?

Comment: I had the problem locally. And just checked, I have the same code as you do, my production app i running fine. I can think off 2 things. 1: It might be that they updated the production and it broke your code due to version differences. 2: Try to re-publish you code.

Comment: Solved by reworking and redeploying my code. I suspect it has to do with the new version update.